# More efficient JOIN without an index

Tags: mysql, database, join

From time to time I need to join two big tables via something like

```
SELECT t1.x + t2.x FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (some_unimportant_column)
```

and it takes ages as both tables are big and there's no index on `some_unimportant_column`. I don't want to keep the index as it costs disk space and time during updates; moreover, sometimes I need a join `USING (another_unimportant_column)`.

While this JOIN isn't frequent enough to justify the index, it's not rare enough to wait an hour for the extremely inefficient computation. What works quite well is

- create an index on the column in one table
- perform the JOIN
- drop the index

but doing this manually is tedious and the commits due to the DDL commands are nasty.

I wonder why the database can't figure this out itself? I'm using mysql and also wonder if other DB engines are smarter about this?

Comment: Since an index is a b-tree, and if you join on something that isn't in a b-tree there is no other choice than to traverse the entire data-structure until the match is found. Using the index, you'd need only a few hops to find the appropriate match. If you **need** the index, then use it. Disks are huge these days, and if databases come close to 50gb - it's likely that they will have to be distributed anyway so I wouldn't think twice before creating an index as important as this.

Comment: @N.B.: I know... but I can't create all possible indexes in advance as I really don't know what column I'll JOIN on the next time. The DB can easily estimate that the query is gonna take too long and show some initiative by creating an index itself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a stored procedure.

The stored procedure would create the index, run the sql and then drop the index.